# ERROR DE AUTOMATIZACION VISUAL BASIC 6.0 CON DLL .NET

Tags: vba

Tengo una aplicacion en vb6 en la que convierto una cadena a base64, pero con caracteres especiales al decodificar da valores distintos, por lo que con ayuda de un amigo me contruyo una DLL hecha en .net para consumir desde VB6.
La dll esta registrada y la puedo ver en mi lista de elementos en vb6 pero al ejecutar el codigo marca "Error de automarizacion" y es todo.

Pongo imagen de ejemplo con un proyecto vacio para probar la DLL y en el SET ahi marca el error.

Ambiente:
Maquina virtual vmware con windows 7 Pro Español
visual Basic 6.0 Profesional

Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Yo creo que necesitabas mas pasos, porque uno es codigo compilado, y el otro codigo manejado... pero la verdad, esto fue hace tanto que ya no lo recuerdo...

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo. No tengo mas pasos, la DLL se construyo en .net y solo la registre y el codigo que muestro de vb6 para probar. Realmente no sale ningun error, solo eso